# Как правильно добавлять в историю undo/redo?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, проектирование, события

Я реализую undo/redo систему с помощью паттерна Команда и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Если добавлять в историю изменений после изменения текста:

Предположим, что textBox.Text изначально имеет какой-то текст (например, "1"). Назначен этот текст в design mode или run time неважно. Главное, что потом пользователь вводит в него, скажем, "2" и textBox.Text становится равным "12". В undo/redo историю попадает "12". Но, если теперь нажать Ctrl+Z, то "2" никуда не денется, т.к. предыдущего элемента истории с единичкой нет и соответственно textBox.Text не может стать равным "1".

Если добавлять в историю изменений до изменения текста:

В этом случае "1" добавится в историю и откат произойдет как надо, но вместе с этим мы никогда не получим текст "12", нажимая на redo, т.к. элемента с этим текстом в истории не существует, потому что добавление происходит ДО изменения текста.

Comment: Так никто же не мешает записать в историю начальное состояние. После запуска запишите в историю "1", а после изменения "12"

Comment: Я не могу добавлять в историю после запуска. Пользователь имеет возможность влиять на тексты полей, путем выбора некоторого элемента в списке. Свойства элемента списка - объекта автоматом прописываются во множество полей (изначальное состояние), после чего он может их изменять. Например, полей 150. Сразу после отображения свойств, добавить все 150 значений в историю? Тогда как будет происходить откат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно для undo/rеdo используют иной алгоритм.

Вместо сохранения состояния буфера (поля) в стеке Undo сохраняют *команду* (с необходимыми аргументами)*, которая изменила буфер*. Для команд удаления надо запоминать удаленные символы.

Команда undo перемещает вершину стека Undo (т.е. последнюю команду модификации буфера) в стек Redo и выполняет действия *обратные* этой команде.

Команда redo перебрасывает вершину стека Redo в стек Undo и исполняет эту команду.

Команды модифицирующие буфер (не в режиме undo/redo) сбрасывают Redo стек.

Comment: Для каких-то простейших операций типа изменения текста это вполне подходит, но что делать, если в некоторых случаях хранить именно состояние на порядок легче, чем накатывать микро изменения? Получается смесь из паттерна Хранителя и Команды. Возможно ли это? Если да, то как?

Comment: Ну, **если на порядок легче**, то что мешает это реализовать? А с паттернами Вы особо не заморачивайтесь, по сути паттерны это просто названия определенных приемов проектирования/программирования, которые в чистом виде на практике редко проходят, на практике всегда будет какая-то смесь и есть ли смысл искать в ней канинические паттерны это большой вопрос.

Comment: Кстати, например emacs, объединяет несколько одинаковых последовательных "микроопераций" в одну и откатывает за одно undo (а вот накаывает "redo" опять маленькими частями (наследие MIT AI Lab?))

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу особенных проблем.

Ваша цепочка состояний должна быть такой:

Начало:

```
[ 1 ]
  ^
  |
 текущее
```

После добавления 2:

```
[ 1 ] [ 12 ]
        ^
        |
      текущее
```

После отката назад:

```
[ 1 ] [ 12 ]
  ^
  |
текущее
```

После возврата:

```
[ 1 ] [ 12 ]
        ^
        |
      текущее
```

Но правильнее всё же, как и советует в соседнем ответе @avp, держать в списке не *состояния*, а *изменения*.

Comment: _"Не вижу особенных проблем"_ -- представьте текст на 10 мб и 1000 изменений/сохранений. поэтому лучше хранить не текст, и не команды изменения буфера, а строки, которые были изменены.

Comment: @Stack: Это последний абзац моего ответа, собственно. Вопрос ведь больше о логике отслеживания изменений.